# The anchor property of components when the application is maximized in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have three buttons placed at the right on my form. The buttons' anchor property parameters **akTop**, **akRight** are set to **true**, the other ones left to **false** so that the buttons always remain at the right side near the boarder when the form is resized. Then I set the form's **WindowState** property to **wsMaximized** so that it covers the whole screen when run at start-up. But when I start the application the buttons are closer to the middle rather than on the right. But when I resize the form at design-time everything seems to work just fine.

Here are some snapshots to show you exactly what I mean:

At design-time:

[image]

[image]

At run-time:

[image]

Please, explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this so that it works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the buttons are being created with their designed positions, the form is then set to Maximized, then the anchor properties are set or put in place.

In design time the anchors are already set and so that’s why you see them move as you want. To prove my theory on this make the form much smaller, run the application and notice that the items are in their smaller design time locations.

An easy fix to get what you want. Keep the Window state at wsNormal and on FormShow (which occurs after Create) do this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

You will see the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your answer in one of those tutorials. But realy dont remember was which one. You can watch all videos, even you will learn more things. it will not time waste all the way.

Link: [Learn Delphi TV](http://learndelphi.tv/)

Also you can try something like below if you are lazy enough to watch videos. Put this code in form resize:

```
buttoncreate.left := panel.width - (buttoncreate.width + buttonedit.width + buttondelete.width);
buttonedit.left := panel.width - (buttonedit.width + buttondelete.width);
buttondelete.left := panel.width - buttondelete.width;
```